# Is there a way to view the list of assets in a shared Earth Engine asset folder?

Tags: google-earth-engine

If my co-worker shares an asset folder with me (e.g. `user/coworkername/somefolder`) and provides writer permissions, then is there a way that I can view the contents of this folder within the 'Asset Manager' on the Google Earth Engine interface. Otherwise, I have to know the exact name of each asset in order to import it, rather than being able to browse the assets within that folder to identify the one that I need.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you only have read access to a shared asset folder, it is possible to see the contents using the ee.data.listAssets() function.

for example:

```
var assetList = ee.data.listAssets("user/coworkername/somefolder");
print(assetList);
```

from the docs:

> Returns a list of the contents in an asset collection or folder.
> Arguments:
>
> parent (String)
>
> params (api.ProjectsAssetsListAssetsNamedParameters, optional):>

> Options: pageSize (defaults to 1000), pageToken, filter (see >https://google.aip.dev/160), view (default is 'FULL', may be 'BASIC').
> callback (Function, optional):
>
> If not supplied, the call is made synchronously.
>
> Returns: api.ListAssetsResponse

However, the asset content is in this case not  visible from the 'Asset Manager', as asked by the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have reader/writer permissions, the asset *should* show up under the 'Assets' tab on the left-hand side on the web interface.

If you're comfortable using the command line, you can also use GEE's [Command Line Tool](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/command_line). Use `earthengine ls user/coworkername/somefolder/` to list all assets in that folder.